# pygame ainmation not showing when moving left

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to learn PyGame and wrote code for a simple game where you can only move left and right, how ever the animation for moving left doesn't show, however the animation for moving right does show.

I've tried going through the code my self but cant seem to find the mistake.

```py
walkright = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkleft = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.Png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]

bg = pygame.image.load('bg1.jpg')
char= pygame.image.load('standing.png')

def redrawgamewindow():

    global walkcount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    if walkcount +1 >= 27 :
        walkcount = 0
    if right :
        win.blit(walkright[walkcount//3],(x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    elif left:
        win.blit(walkleft[walkcount//3], (x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    else :
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 852 - width - vel:
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True
    else :
        left = False
        right = False
        walkcount= 0
    if not (isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkcount = 0
    else:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0 :
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpcount **2 )* 0.5 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1

        else:
            isjump = False
            jumpcount = 10

    redrawgamewindow()

pygame.quit()
```

No error messages show up when I move left.

Comment: Are you sure about `x < 852 - width - vel`? Shouldn't it be `x < width - vel:` or `x < 852 - vel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't implement a game loop by a recursive function:

> ```py
> def redrawgamewindow():
>
>    # [...]
>
>    redrawgamewindow()
> ```

Use a `while` loop. The display has to be updated in the loop in every frame.

```py
def redrawgamewindow():

    run = True
    while run:

        # [...]
```

You do the update of the display only in case of "`not left and not right`":

```py
def redrawgamewindow():
    global walkcount

    run = True
    while run:

        win.blit(bg, (0,0))
        if walkcount +1 >= 27 :
            walkcount = 0
        if right :
            win.blit(walkright[walkcount//3],(x, y))
            walkcount += 1
        elif left:
            win.blit(walkleft[walkcount//3], (x, y))
            walkcount += 1
        else :
            win.blit(char, (x, y))
            pygame.display.update() # <--- DELETE

        # [...]

        pygame.display.update() # <--- INSERT

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        # [...]
```